# App Store updates Affinity Designer over and over again

Tags: mac-appstore

My App Store updates Affinity Designer to version 1.2.1 and then it does it again and again and again... I tried to uninstall Affinity Designer but that didn't help. Zombie-Affinity Designer came back from trash and wants to be updated again. any ideas?

[image]

**edit:**

it solved itself. i guess apple had issues with the app store.

Comment: if no joy with @unknowndomain 's answer, try Fix permissions in Disk Utility, then run the latest combo updater .. 10.10.4 is at https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1820

Answer (score 1):

Try deleting the app and reinstalling from your purchased apps list.